# I keep getting an error 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'VALUES'.'

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I am trying to update my database in C# but I keep get this message error

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'VALUES'.'

This is my code to update the database:

```
public void updateTheStack(string name, int quant)
{
        connect.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Items ('Quantity') VALUES (@Quantity) WHERE Name = @Name", connect);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantity", quant);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", name);

        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        connect.Close();
}
```

and my database:

[image]

I think it must be an error with my query.

Comment: The [Official Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) should always be your first port of call.

Comment: Since your `UDPATE` Isn't returning any result set, you should **NOT** use `ExecuteReader()`, but `ExecuteNonQuery()` instead .....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a straight up syntax issue, that looks like you've confused/conflated an UPDATE with a typical pattern for an INSERT

Typical update:

```
UPDATE table 
SET column = value, column2 = value2 
WHERE othercolumn = othervalue
```

Typical insert:

```
INSERT INTO table (column, column2) VALUES (value, value2)
```

I see where you were going with your new syntax for UPDATE ;) but it's just a "you'll have to remember they're like this"

---

Side note, you should read http://dapper-tutorial.com - your life is too short to be writing laborious, repetitive, boring database access code like this

Answer (score 1):

your [update query](https://www.w3schools.com/SQL/sql_update.asp) is incorrect, Syntax is be

```
UPDATE table_name   //table_name is Items
SET column1 = value1, column2 = value2, ...   //column1 is Quantity
WHERE condition;      //Condition is Name = @name
```

---

Your code looks like,

```
public void updateTheStack(string name, int quant)
{
    connect.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Items SET Quantity = @Quantity  WHERE Name = @Name", connect);

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantity", quant);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", name);

    var recordCount = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    connect.Close();
}
```

---

As @marc_s said, Update query is not returning any result set, you should use [ExecuteNonQuery()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) instead of [ExecuteReader()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executereader?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1)

> Executes a Transact-SQL statement against the connection and returns
> the number of rows affected.

Comment: Since your `UDPATE` Isn't returning any result set, you should **NOT** use `ExecuteReader()`, but `ExecuteNonQuery()` instead .....

Comment: When people use AddWithValue with a *parameterized query* against SQL Server, it's good to point them to having a read of [this blog](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/), though if they use stored procedures or a non sqlserver database, I don't mention it

Comment: @CaiusJard, thanks for the reference, I will read this blog first and will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: No probs! ps; reason I don't mention it with stored procs is it's less of an issue because the parameter type is declared at the sqlserver end rather than inferred. Reason I don't mention it with non SQLS databases is because it doesn't always matter and some eg MySQL actively recommend using it. I've seen people even give downvotes for answers that mention AddWithValue, which is ridiculous; i'd far prefer the whole world parameterized queries even if by AWV as it would kill off SQL injection hacking. Queries running slow because of bad type inference is far less a problem than injection